# What is the std::map<string,bool> equivilant in asp.net?

Tags: c#, asp.net

What would be the closest thing to `std::map<string,bool>` in asp.net?

Comment: Dictionary<String, bool>?

Answer (score 4):

**[Dictionary](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xfhwa508.aspx)**.

```
Dictionary<string, bool>
```

Answer (score 2):

I think you'd probably use:

```
System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary<string,bool>
```

Answer (score 0):

The `Dictionary` collection is a hashtable. `System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary<string,bool>` is most similar data structure to `std::map<string,bool>`.